# Program freezes when I start a web driver in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I start a chrome web driver using selenium python, the program doesn't continue after the line that the web driver was initialized

```
from selenium import webdriver

print('Starting webdriver') # This line is executed
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C://bin//chromedriver.exe') # This line is executed

# Nothing after the line above is executed
print('Webdriver started') # This line isn't executed
```

Comment: Update the question with the binery version information and trace logs.

Comment: @DebanjanB What are trace logs? Binary version of what and how do I get it? Sorry, I am fairly new with selenium so I don't know what I am doing

Comment: your code seems right and usually right codes dont fail , there might be some issues with your driver or your need to add the errors from terminal for understanding

Comment: I will look more into it, thanks for the suggestions @ManishChaudhary